# manage size of presented tableviewController

Tags: ios, ios7

I have presented a tableview controller on a view controller.That tableview comes as full screen on view controller but I do not want to present the tableview on full screen.Is there any way to manage the size of presented vie controller. And the second problem is that i want to present a vie controller which have some label , some text boxes and a table view. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could not change the size of the presented view controller. Another way to do it is by adding it as `childViewController` by:

```
 [self.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];
 [self addChildViewController:tableView];
```

Then you can change the size of the `tableViewController` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

- IF you are using iphone device then the viewcontroller will occupy
  the full screen .
- If the device is iPad,then u can use modalPresentStyle.

> ```
>  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourVC];
>     navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
>  [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

- For iPhone ,add the views like UILabel,UITableview to the mainView and present it.
  [image: VC]

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableViewController` is used when the table view is the main view of the controller.

In your case it seems more appropriate to use a normal (subclass of) `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` as one of its sub views.
Then you can resize it as you prefer and add other elements (labels...) as additional subviews.

Usually in this configuration you may want to set the view controller as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view.

Does this answer also your first question?